# Asyncallback function how to wait it for completed and get result when call

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I have 2 function

```
public void sendGETRequest()
        {
            System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri(urlAdress);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers["X_USERNAME"] = username;
            request.Headers["X_PASSWORD"] = password;
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request);
        }

        private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
        {           
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();                
            }
            myResponse.Close();
            if (Completed != null)
                Completed();
        }
    }
```

When I call

```
 GET user;   
    public String GETUserList()
    {
      user  = new GET();
      user.urlAdress = url + "user";
       user.username = username;
       user.password = password;

       user.sendGETRequest();

       user.Completed += OutUser;

       if (Completed != null)
           Completed();


       return user.result;
    }


void OutUser()
            {
               Debug.WriteLine(user.result);
            }
```

**if I CALL 1 ACTION  like this To get list of user**

```
String json = GETUserList();
            Debug.WriteLine("Hllllllllllll" + json + "HHHHHHHHHHHHHH" + p.resultWords);
```

**It return**

```
HllllllllllllHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
[{"id":"3","username":"a","password":"a"},{"id":"4","username":"bbbb\n","password":"aaa"},{,{"id":"13","username":"abcdef","password":"abcdef"},{"id{"id":"10","word":"AAAAddddA","definition":"aaa","cardset_id":"2"},{"id":"11","word":"AAAAddddA","definition":"aaa","cardset_id":"2"},{"id":"12","word":"asdas","definition":"asdasd","cardset_id":"1"},{"id":"13","word":"asdas","definition":"asdasd","cardset_id":"1"},{"id":"14","word":"AAAAddddA","definition":"aaa","cardset_id":"2"},{"id":"15","word":"AAAAddddA","definition":"aaa","cardset_id":"2"},{"id":"16","word":"asdas","definition":"asdasd","
```

I think function  **ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)** is run in background and when **I Call to get list of User**  it execute after that (I've debugged.
How to make it run before action completed?
Thank for advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it works:

```
BeginGetResponse -> makes an asynchronous web request
asynchronous request completed -> makes a callback: ReadWebRequestCallback
ReadWebRequestCallback -> read the response
```

So it seems that you want to wait for `ReadWebRequestCallback` before you reach the return statement in `GETUserList()`... then don't issue an asynchronous request. Doing anything else effectively defeats the purpose of issuing the asynchronous request.

You can use a manual reset event:

```
public class GETUser
{
    public ManualResetEvent mrse = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    // other fields 
}
```

In

```
public String GETUserList()
{
    user  = new GET();
    user.urlAdress = url + "user";
    user.username = username;
    user.password = password;

    user.sendGETRequest();

    user.Completed += OutUser;

    if (Completed != null)
       Completed();

    user.mrse.WaitOne(); // <--- block until the event is raised
    return user.result;
}
```

And in the callback:

```
private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{           
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

    using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();                
    }
    myResponse.Close();
    if (Completed != null)
        Completed();

    mrse.Signal();// <-- signal that you have finished reading
}
```

Again, this defeats the purpose of making an asynchronous web request.

Comment: Sorry my english is bad. I've edited
I wanna call sendGETRequest to get List Of User I want assign result of sendGETRequest to variable.

Comment: mrse.Sigal() is it available for windowphone7.1?

Comment: @chanhle, should be... I would assume that windowphone 7.1 is using the .NET framework and `ManualResetEvent` has been in there fore a while: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx